# How to store a value after deleting the parent object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to store a value independently from the parent object, so if I want to delete it my value will keep stay inside the program.

I'm not using a database, my MVC is linked to a library framework with repositories

The model

```
    namespace FarmMVC.Models
    {
      public abstract class AnimalViewModel
      {
        protected AnimalViewModel()
        {

        }
        protected AnimalViewModel(AnimalBase a)
        {
          Name = a.Name;
          Age = a.Age;
          Weight = a.Weight;
          Breed = a.Breed;
          Gender = a.Gender;
          ParticularSigns = a.ParticularSigns;
          Color = a.Color;
          Meat = a.Meat;         
        }

          public int Meat { get; set; }
          public int MeatProduction { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

The Controller

```
    namespace FarmMVC.Controllers
    {
      public class AnimalsController : Controller
      {
        public ActionResult GoatMilk(string name)
        {
          var rep = new GoatRepository();
          var goat = rep.GetByName(name);

          var model = FarmFactory.CreateAnimalModel<GoatViewModel>(goat) as GoatViewModel;

          model.MilkProduction = rep.MilkProduction(goat);

          var list = rep.GetAll().Select(g => FarmFactory.CreateAnimalModel<GoatViewModel>(g)).ToList();

          return View("~/Views/Animals/Goats.cshtml", list);
        }
      }  
    }
```

The View

```
   @model IEnumerable<FarmMVC.Models.GoatViewModel>

   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MeatProduction)
        @Model.Sum(i => i.Meat)
     </div>
   </div>
```

How I can keep track of what kind of object I'm working on

```
  namespace FarmMVC.Factories
  {
    public static class FarmFactory
    {
      public static T CreateAnimalModel<T>(AnimalBase a)
        where T : AnimalViewModel
      {

          return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), a);

      }
    }
  }
```

The method

```
   namespace Farm.Repositories
   {
     public class GoatRepository : GenericRepository<Goat>
     {
       public int MeatProduction(Goat goat)
       {
          if (goat == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(goat));
          }


          if (goat.Age > 13 && goat.Weight >= 50 && goat.Weight <= 100)
          {
              goat.Meat += getrandom.Next(3, 6);
              Remove(goat);
          }
          else if (goat.Weight > 100)
          {
              goat.Meat += getrandom.Next(5, 9);
              Remove(goat);
          }
          else if (IsDead(goat))
          {
              goat.Meat += getrandom.Next(2, 4);
              Remove(goat);
          }

          return goat.Meat;
        }
      }
    }
```

In the last 2 lines of the controller I need to store everything inside a list since I'm working on IEnumerables, but since I already deleted the object inside the method I get back nothing, but I need to keep track of the Meat value

Thanks

Comment: you should create a ViewModel with your informations (list of GOAT,the variable model and variable goat if you need it) then send this ViewModel to your  Goats.cshtml to display what you want ... hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I worked on that for a while. How can you send the ViewModel to Goats.cshtml if that View already use a different Model? I thought that wasn't possible